# Decorator with different argument signature

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to simplify method definition for my django views with decorators. For that I require that decorator takes different amount of arguments, then wrapped method. I tried:

```
from functools import wraps

def mydecorator(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff with slugs
        slugs = {
            # more stuff with slugs
        }
        return fn(self, slugs)
    return wrapper


class Decorated:
    @mydecorator
    def mymethod(self, slugs):
        print(slugs)


obj = Decorated
obj.mymethod('haha', 'hehe', 'hoho')
```

I always seem to get either error, or one parameter missing.
Please show me the way to do this

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it seems like part of the problem is here:

```
obj = Decorated
```

which likely should be:

```
obj = Decorated()
```

Presumably you meant to instantiate a `Decorated` object, not call `mymethod()` as a class method.

As for a missing parameter, it's not clear if you mean to consolidate all of the parameters into whatever `slugs` is, but normally you want the decorator to pass all of the remaining arguments to the wrapped function, like this:

```
return fn(self, slugs, *args, **kwargs)
```